# SQL Stored Procedure Convert Date Parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a SQL stored procedure which accepts two dates, however when I send them in my open query, Oracle does not like the date format for some reason.

How can I change the dateformat to `YYYY-MM-DD` from `dd-mm-yyyy` in the stored procedure before sending using it.

e.g `SET @startdate = CONVERT`

Answer (score 4):

Use the [TO_DATE function](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) to convert a string value into an Oracle DATE data type.

To accept a date string in the format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
v_start_date DATE := TO_DATE(v_date_string, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

To accept a date string in the format DD-MM-YYYY:

```
v_start_date DATE := TO_DATE(v_date_string, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `TO_CHAR` function of Oracle.

```
/*retrieve from query*/
select TO_CHAR(reg_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') REGDATE from Users_TBL 

/*Assign to variable*/
regDate := TO_CHAR(reg_date,'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: If Oracle's not accepting the format, it's not an issue with an existing DATE value.

Comment: TO_DATE function doesn't work for "YYYY-MM-DD" format. That's why try to use "TO_CHAR" instead of "TO_DATE".

Comment: "`YYYY-MM-DD`" is perfectly fine for both TO_DATE and TO_CHAR. It just depends on which direction you're converting between date and string.